# How to create back dated Release in Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

Ideally I would create a release in gitlab whenever I deploy to production. This is based on a git tag. Practically though, sometimes, I forget to create the release (say, v10.1.0) right away, and only realize later after 1 or 2 releases (v11.0.0 and v11.1.0) that the release notes for a previous release aren't available. 
Now, in such cases, I edit the Release Notes for the appropriate tag (v10.0.1) and create a new release (v10.0.1). This works fine, but, this new release now appears at the top of the Releases page on Gitlab, although, I would like it to appear in order of deploying to production, which was 1 or 2 releases ago. This way, when someone looks at the release notes, the release notes at the top might be for some older release (v10.0.1), which does not give an idea about when was the latest deployment to production (v11.1.0) and what are the release notes for that.

I can't find any config options in gitlab to create a backdated release. Any help with gitlab options or the workflow would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out a way to do this using Gitlab api.

- `PUT` request to your.gitlab.domain/api/v4/projects/:projectID/releases/:releaseId
- need to add a **PRIVATE-TOKEN** in header (token can be obtained from gitlab UI)
- add the "`released_at`" field in the json body with appropriate value.

After the request is successful, gitlab UI shows the releases in expected order.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#update-a-release